# Determined/determining to make a good beginning, these new comers did all they could

Tags: grammar, participles, active-vs-passive

I encountered an exercise on an app today, which asks me to choose a right word for the sentence:

> _____ to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.

A. To be determined

B. Determined

C. Being determined

D. Determining

I thought the answer was obviously B but the app says it's D. The given explanation says the active voice should be used here and hence the choice D. But I don't really trust that answer more than myself so I'd like a second opinion from a native speaker. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either B or C would be equally fine here. D doesn't sound as good.

"Determined" can be seen as an adjective here, just like "eager," and both B and C sound perfectly fine regardless of whether I use "determined" or "eager":

> **Eager** to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.
>
> **Being eager** to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.
>
> **Determined** to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.
>
> **Being determined** to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.

(The meaning of "eager" isn't quite the same as the meaning of "determined," though.)

According to [the Wiktionary page "determine"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/determine#English), the word "determining" can mean "resolving" or "intending," so option D also makes sense. But I've never actually heard the word "determining" used that way before; when I first saw option D, I was sure that it was a mistake. I would use the word "resolving" instead of "determining":

> **Resolving** to make a good beginning, these new-comers did all that they could to get themselves well-prepared.

---

Side note:

I don't think the phrases "determined to make a good beginning" and "being determined to make a good beginning" are in the passive voice. The first phrase can't be in the passive voice because it doesn't have a form of the verb "to be." The second phrase could conceivably be in the passive voice, but it makes more sense to see it as a stative use of the word "being," along with the adjective "determined." The active voice of this phrase would be "[something] determining them to make a good beginning."

Answer (score -1):

At a first glance B looks like a correct choice. Being that the active voice is being used, D portrays that they are currently determining/ making a decision to make a good beginning.

Comment: I don't know...would you say that D is better than B without further context? Also, given that the verb in the sentence is "did", I don't think "currently determining" makes much sense.

Comment: Choice D is not grammatical. Choice B or possibly C would be OK.

Comment: @ColleenV That's what I thought. Can you elaborate a little, grammar-wise, so that I can also convince other?

Comment: B and D can be correct, depending on what your trying to say. In this case they are deciding to make a good decision therefore D is correct. B would be used if they would be in the state of being determined. D is showing that they are doing the act of determining.

Comment: “Determining to make a good start” is not grammatical. The new-comers were determined (adjective). They were not determining something (transitive verb). I’m sorry I don’t have the time to write up a proper answer, maybe this will help your answer Nicki.

Comment: As implied by his app, the newcomers were not in the state of being determined but rather determining their decision.

Comment: 'Determined' because _did_ all they could. It describes a past event (it's not 'these new-comers _do_ all they can')

Comment: @Nicki But I don't think that's a common use of the word "determining." It makes sense to say "determining that they should make a good start," or "deciding to make a good start," or "committing to make a good start," but not "determining to make a good start."

Comment: @TannerSwett I agree that "determining to make a good start" is not commonly used. It works fine grammatically to justify why the app selected that as the correct choice.